# How can I upload to google drive api without required user to login?

Tags: google-drive-api, google-drive-picker

Is this something doable with google drive api? I've stuck on it from days. I used `gapi`and tried with it till the very end but each http request requires an `access_token` which is generated from user login.

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: @Julia, I have an app where I need users to simply upload a huge files (~Gbs) and then a mechanism to see the files; whether by api or direct links. What do you think the best case for this!

Comment: It sounds like a service like Google Cloud Storage would be a better fit.

Comment: Where are these files supposed to be stored in (in your Drive account or in the user's Drive) ? Are you using [Drive Picker API](https://developers.google.com/picker/docs)? Do you basically want users to upload files to your Drive without them having to be logged in (i.e any annonymous user) ? Could you also please share a sample code with no sensitive information of your implementation? Thanks !